# How do I go from truffle testrpc to mainnet?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, metamask, truffle-contract

I've been teaching myself ethereum via the stack `solidity/truffle/truffle-contract/testrpc/metamask`. I built a small dApp that runs on testrpc with proper unit tests which work great. I've written a function that I `truffle serve` that loads my contract named VEX from the local the file `f_deployed_contract`

```
$.getJSON(f_deployed_contract, function(data) {
    App.contracts.VEX = TruffleContract(data);
    App.contracts.VEX.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
});
```

Everything works! I was excited, so I deployed the contract of the working solidity code using a combination of [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) and [Ether Wallet](https://wallet.ethereum.org/) to the mainnet. It was mined and now lives here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe5e6c5d463815e339a2aac2e92594de595e2029e6448997799871d8cb2a5728b

Now, how do I adjust my `TruffleContract` so I can use my dApp with metamask on the mainnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TruffleContract, you can just specify the address of your contract when trying to interact with it. From the documenation:

```
var MetaCoin = require("./path/to/MetaCoin.sol.js");
MetaCoin.at(contract_address).then(function(instance) {
   //do promise things
}
```

So, Instead of using `Metacoin.deployed()` , which you're probably using, , you could use `.at(address)`.

Also, your contract lives at 0x4f5a4501f96cb95eeda376f4caa0b24f4dbbd796, not 0xe5e6c5d463815e339a2aac2e92594de595e2029e6448997799871d8cb2a5728b. The second one is the transaction which created your contract, the first one is the address of your contract.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I deploy multiple copies of the same contract (same bytecode but in different places), I can just call the different contracts by using `.at(address)` for each one?

Comment: that would be correct